# iOS Facebook SDK - Session auto closes

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

This is my first time using Facebook SDK so maybe the login/permissions flow is not right, though I followed Facebook tutorial. My application just needs to share on the wall, I am using SDK 3.2.1.

Everytime the user taps the share button I use `+ (BOOL)openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:(NSArray*)readPermissions allowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI completionHandler:(FBSessionStateHandler)handler` method to login.

The very first time asks for e-mail/password combination. The issue I am facing is it will not reuse the stored token afterwards:

- If the token is stored (user logged to Facebook previously), the app
  will ask for permissions with the "You already authorized app_name",
  then it will most likely ask again when sharing.
- If `openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions` is called a second time, it
  won't ask for any permissions.
- The third time is called it will ask again.

I found the session is being automatically closed but I have no idea why. The completion handler shows how `FBSessionStateClosed` is received just before `FBSessionStateOpen`. And I guess this is the reason for Facebook SDK to keep asking every other time for approval.

[image: Completion block Session Closed]
[image: Completion block Session Open]

These 2 traces are from the 2nd time `openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions` is called (you can see how the session is closed and opened again). The next time the method is called, it will just receive a closed session and will ask with the "already authorized" screen.

My code is somewhat like below:

```
- (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI {
    return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil
                                              allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
                                         completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                             FBSessionState state,
                                                             NSError *error) {
                                             [self sessionStateChanged:session
                                                                 state:state
                                                                 error:error];
                                         }];
}

- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session
                      state:(FBSessionState) state
                      error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (state) {
        case FBSessionStateOpen:
            if (!error) {
                // We have a valid session
                NSLog(@"User session found");
            }
            break;
        case FBSessionStateClosed:
        case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
            [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     postNotificationName:FBSessionStateChangedNotification
     object:session];
}
```

I hope someone can help on this one, I am quite frustrated.

Comment: Have you tried printing out the error?

Comment: @MingLi There's no error (is nil), just the annoying browser screen asking for permission but saying "you already approved <app_name>". BTW this only happens with browser based login, if I set up my Facebook account on iOS settings it never asks for any permissions (just the very first time)

Comment: When you say browser screen, do you mean it switched over to mobile Safari, or a webview (or maybe Facebook app)? Also, do you have the right url scheme set up in your app, and implemented application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation: in your AppDelegate?

Comment: @MingLi I mean Safari. And yes openURL is implemented and the url schema set up according to their tutorial